# Restangular $object and then

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a problem, I would like execute a task after Restangular. And use $object for return data when the task is done.

```
return Restangular.one('ads', path).customGET("search", params).$object.then(function(){
    overlay.set(false);
});
```

But i have an undefined.

Thanks

Comment: Did you answer your question? I think the error is because the `.$object` is undefined till it is resolved... I"m looking for a way around this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the task in your case is setting the overlay to false. And you want to use an $object member. To simulate that, You can do this:

```
var adsPromise = Restangular.one('ads', path)
 .customGET("search", params).then(function(result){
  overlay.set(false);
  return {$object:result}
});
return adsPromise;
```

See some of @mgonto, chief Restangular Gaucho, for his [samples](http://plnkr.co/edit/uQFJ7T?p=preview) of chaining these and handling the promises.